# Funny behavior using urlretrieve on a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, urllib

I wrote some code to download some files from URLs, which I put in a dict, however, when I run the script, everything runs fine, except in the end when it goes to download the files, it creates creates one file with one of the names, then I see that file get larger and larger, and then it gets smaller again. This file (mp4) is always unplayable/corrupt, and there's only ever one, it never moves on to another. Any idea what's going on? My guess is that somehow python keeps downloading the different files to the one local file and overwriting, I don't understand why though.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import os 
import re 
import urllib 
import urllib.request


urlfilebytes = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/sciencenow/download/index.html')
urlfile = urlfilebytes.read().decode('utf-8')
urls = re.findall(r'(http://www-tc.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/sciencenow/media/downloads/\S+)"', urlfile)
print(urls)
names = re.findall(r'NSN_\S+.mp4', str(urls))
print(names)
names_to_urls = {}
for name in names:
  for url in urls:
    names_to_urls[name] = url
print(names_to_urls)
for key in names_to_urls.keys():
  for value in names_to_urls.values():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(value, key)
```

Comment: your first loop sets all dict entries to the last url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want instead of your for loops is just:

```
for name, url in zip(names, urls):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, name)
```

You don't want nested loops: you're getting all combinations of URL with name instead of just the matching pairs of URL and name. `zip(names, urls)` takes the first item of each list, then the second from each list, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I changed that, but when I try to run that I get ValueError: read of closed file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ViHRimjt works for me on Python 2.7. If you change the `import urllib` line to `import urllib.request as urllib` I think it will work on Python 3.

Comment: Okay, I'm running a modified version in 2.6.1,so far so good!

Comment: Okay it's working now! I changed all python 3 specific parts to python 2.6 and now it works.